# Open Context menu on click of Menu button in android

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

How to open a context menu on click of menu button on android device? Can anyone help me please..

```
@Override  
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Gmail");  
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Facebook");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Twitter");  
}  

@Override  
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    if(item.getTitle()=="Gmail"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Facebook"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Twitter"){function3(item.getItemId());}  

    return true;  
}
```

How open the above context menu on click of menu button ?

Comment: in context menu you must have to pass View as argument. so its not possible. and you have to open context menu on menu button then why you don't use direct option menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Are you sure you want to open context Menu on Click of Menu button?
```

Because, **Context Menu is for a specific view,**

A contextual menu offers actions that affect a specific item or context frame in the UI. You can provide a context menu for any view, but they are most often used for items in a ListView, GridView, or other view collections in which the user can perform direct actions on each item.

To show a context menu on long click, most clients will want to call `registerForContextMenu(View)` and override `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu, View, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)`.

For menu Button of device you can use an [Options Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

**Update:**

I never try this, but you can do something like,

1. Handle Menu button press event of device,

   ```
   public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            // ........
        }
       return true;
    }
   ```
2. Put line inside it,

   ```
   this.openContextMenu(view); // Here view is reference for which you have a register contect menu..
   ```